# Sci-fi book about man who built an interstellar ship with the use of a collider and met his enemy inside of the Sun

Tags: story-identification, books, space

The main character of the book finds out that he built an interstellar ship with the use of a collider and then removed his memory to refuse from interstellar travel. He also had a suit built with the use of a collider. Both could resist any heat, even inside of the Sun.

Throughout the story, he tries to find his enemy, but can't, and at the end he goes inside of the Sun to avoid any external interference and realises that his enemy is very tiny and had been on his ship all along.
I think the name of this book is the name of the ship, but I can't remember it.

I read this book about 15 years ago. I used electronic version so don't know how cover looked like.

I assume it was published in 1980-1990s.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this, and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Hoping not to give offense, but I suspect that English is not your first language; did you read this in English or in another language?  If another, which?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This sounds like John C. Wright's [Golden Oecumene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Oecumene) series.

**The main character of the book finds out that he built an interstellar ship with the use of a collider and then removed his memory to refuse from interstellar travel. He also had a suit built with the use of a collider. Both could resist any heat, even inside of the Sun.**

From this [review](https://www.sfsite.com/07b/ga132.htm)

> That man is Phaethon, an engineer and visionary who, as The Golden Age
> begins, discovers that he has recently entered into an agreement to
> wipe most of the last two hundred and fifty years of his life from his
> memory. His attempts to find out why he agreed to have his memory
> erased and whether he should seek to regain his memories form the
> narrative structure of the story.

From the book itself:

> The expense of this suit was staggering. The material was rare; only
> the supercollider that orbited the equator of Jupiter could generate
> sufficient energy to create the artificial atoms, and even that
> required a major percentage of the output of the small star that
> Gannis had made by igniting Jupiter. This suit had been constructed
> one atom at a time. The black material, now inside the suit, was
> cyclic nano-machinery, which would form a self-contained and
> selfsustaining symbiosis with the wearer: a miniature and complete
> ecosystem. But what in the world was it for? Swimming among the
> granules of the sun? Walking into the core chambers of plasma
> reactors?

**I think the name of this book is the name of the ship, but I can't remember it.**

The second book in the series is **The Phoenix Exultant** which is the name of Phaeton's ship.

Comment: I’m so grateful! That’s the book! I was looking for it for so many years!

Comment: I'm very glad to help.